# What is the exact percentage of spectral changes that human pinnae introduces into the acoustic input signal?

Tags: hearing

I read somewhere that amount of spectral changes that human auricula introduces into the input signal is 6%.

Now I cannot find that literature.

Does anyone know a source that might confirm this, or may confirm this him/her self? Well or contradict it if necessary.

Comment: %of what? dB per frequency band? It depends on various factors, including the acoustic frequency. Could you specify your question?

Comment: Even that is OK info. I am looking for any spectral change introduced by pinnae. Someone just put out, I guess a summarized percentage for all changes caused by pinnae. Intensity/freq ratios i.e. power spectral density changes are fine, if you know where to find the info.

Comment: I can have a look for a decent paper. Please give me 24h. Perhaps adapt your question accordingly as it is quite vague. It may help me and others to formulate an answer. And what do you mean with *even that is OK?* What *is it that you want to know*? Be specific. It's a cool topic though. Happy to spend my time on this :)